# Writing a loop with an integer in python

Tags: python, pandas, loops, integer

I have a dataframe as such:

```
data = [[0xD8E3ED, 2043441], [0xF7F4EB, 912788],[0x000000,6169]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['c_code', 'occurence'])
```

[image: df]

I am attempting to loop through c_code to get an integer value. The following code works to obtain the integer

```
hex_val = '0xFF9B3B'
print(int(hex_val, 0))

16751419
```

But when I try to loop through the column I run into an issue. I currently have this running but am just overwriting every value.

```
for i in range(len(df)):
    df['value'] = int((df['c_code'].iloc[i]), 0)
```

Ideal output would be a df with a value column that reflects the value of the c_code. The image below shows the desired format but notice that the value is the same for all rows. I believe that I need to append rows but I am unsure of how to do that

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that you can modify the type of your column c_code and assign this to a new column.

```
import pandas as pd

data = [['0xD8E3ED', 2043441], ['0xF7F4EB', 912788],['0x000000',6169]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['c_code', 'occurence'])
df['value'] = df['c_code'].apply(int, base=16)
```

Also, I had to put the hexadecimal numbers as strings, if not pandas converts them to int directly.

I get this result:
[image]

Comment: I am now taking that value and applying color diff against a set value (13227184). 

(cie94(rgb2lab(rgb(13227184)), rgb2lab(rgb(df['value'].iloc[0]))))

Color Diff Documentation: https://gist.github.com/fikr4n/368f2f2070e0f9a15fb4#file-coldiff-py

I get a similar error and am only able to work with a single row like before

This appears to be a similar issue with int values

Comment: You should probably try with .apply() instead of looping through your dataset. I'm not familiar with the functions you are trying to use but it looks like basic math so apply should work.

Answer (score 0):

You are assigning the entire column to a new value at each step in the loop

```
df["value"] = ...
```

To specify a row you need to change it to `df["value"][i] = ...`

However, You shouldn't have to loop through each value in Pandas.

try:

```
df["value"] = int(df["c_code"], 0)
```

Comment: I decided to use a loop when I was getting the following error: TypeError: int() can't convert non-string with explicit base

Comment: df['value'][i] = ... seems to disrupt the order in my df.

Comment: I see. using the apply method should overcome the type error `df["value"] = df["c_code"].apply(lambda x: int(x, 0))` https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html

Comment: Thanks! apply method worked